# Multiple apps receive same FCM token on register

Tags: ios, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

**Scenario**

After settings device token:

```
Messaging.messaging().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: MessagingAPNSTokenType.prod)
```

Then calling:

```
let token = Messaging.messaging().fcmToken // Then updating server with token
```

The token is the same for multiple apps!

What results in the user receiving different pushes for wrong applications.

- Yes, I am using different push certificates and google plist files for every app.
- Multiple application is on the same project, but by the documentation, I'ts supposed to be supported.

Comment: Facing the same issue. What is the fix?